# Import tensorflow error, no module named tensorflow in Google cloud

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

Remotely connected to my gcloud vm (compute engine) using ssh through gcloud sdk shell and putty.
Created a sample python script as per the quickstart:
https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart

Trying to run the script but getting error no module named tensorflow.
Have both python 2.7.14 and 3.5.4 installed locally. I can run python scripts locally but not in the gcloud shell.

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Can you run the commands [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#install_tensorflow) and tell us if the packages were installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow packages have to be installed if you want to use them.

First you have to install pip if you haven't done so already:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade \
&& sudo apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev
```

When you have pip installed you have to install the TensorFlow packages:

```
sudo pip install tensorflow
```

You can follow step by step tutorial how to set up VM instance with TensorFlow in Google Cloud [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-distributed-tensorflow-on-compute-engine#creating_the_template_instance)

Comment: Happy to hear that :) Colud you please accept the answer? Thank you.